# PHP Parse can't get user's emails

Tags: php, parsing

Now I am using PHP Parse sdk and I am trying to get all user info.

```
  $query = ParseUser::query();
  $objArray = $query->find();
  $data = array();
  print_r($objArray);
  foreach ($objArray as $obj) {
    $one['id'] =  $obj->getObjectId();
    $one['displayName'] =  $obj->displayName;
    $one['email'] =  $obj->email;
    $data[]=$one;
  }
```

and this is print_r result

```
Array ( [0] => Parse\ParseUser Object ( [_sessionToken:protected] => [serverData:protected] => Array ( [readreceipt] => YES [pushnotification] => YES [usernameFix] => jodydunn [displayName_lower] => jody dunn [displayName] => jody dunn [firstLaunch] => Yes [username] => Judy.Dunn@hotmail.com [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 23404642 [verifiedAccount] => 1 ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [readreceipt] => YES [pushnotification] => YES [usernameFix] => jodydunn [displayName_lower] => jody dunn [displayName] => jody dunn [firstLaunch] => Yes [username] => Judy.Dunn@hotmail.com [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 23404642 [verifiedAccount] => 1 ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [readreceipt] => 1 [pushnotification] => 1 [usernameFix] => 1 [displayName_lower] => 1 [displayName] => 1 [firstLaunch] => 1 [username] => 1 [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 1 [verifiedAccount] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 97EIKQVlUW [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-01-30 14:26:15.568000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-06-12 23:34:47.234000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) [1] => Parse\ParseUser Object ( [_sessionToken:protected] => [serverData:protected] => Array ( [username] => tiagomarques304@yahoo.com [displayName_lower] => tiago marques [usernameFix] => tiagomarques [displayName] => Tiago Marques [firstLaunch] => Yes [readreceipt] => YES [pushnotification] => YES [facebookId] => 1722892281374124 [qbUserID] => 23295999 ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [username] => tiagomarques304@yahoo.com [displayName_lower] => tiago marques [usernameFix] => tiagomarques [displayName] => Tiago Marques [firstLaunch] => Yes [readreceipt] => YES [pushnotification] => YES [facebookId] => 1722892281374124 [qbUserID] => 23295999 ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [username] => 1 [displayName_lower] => 1 [usernameFix] => 1 [displayName] => 1 [firstLaunch] => 1 [readreceipt] => 1 [pushnotification] => 1 [facebookId] => 1 [qbUserID] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => nOsEiFmpLu [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-01-27 16:11:18.737000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-01-27 16:11:37.865000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) [2] => Parse\ParseUser Object ( [_sessionToken:protected] => [serverData:protected] => Array ( [displayName_lower] => jody dunn [firstLaunch] => Yes [displayName] => jody dunn [usernameFix] => jodydunn [username] => jody.dunn@hotmail.com [readreceipt] => YES [pushnotification] => YES [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 23158732 [verifiedAccount] => 1 ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [displayName_lower] => jody dunn [firstLaunch] => Yes [displayName] => jody dunn [usernameFix] => jodydunn [username] => jody.dunn@hotmail.com [readreceipt] => YES [pushnotification] => YES [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 23158732 [verifiedAccount] => 1 ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [displayName_lower] => 1 [firstLaunch] => 1 [displayName] => 1 [usernameFix] => 1 [username] => 1 [readreceipt] => 1 [pushnotification] => 1 [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 1 [verifiedAccount] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => VtvElOtqFQ [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-01-24 11:47:08.461000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-06-12 23:34:24.014000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) [3] => Parse\ParseUser Object ( [_sessionToken:protected] => [serverData:protected] => Array ( [displayName] => Jody dunn [pushnotification] => YES [readreceipt] => YES [username] => Jody.dunn@hotmail.com [firstLaunch] => Yes [usernameFix] => jodydunn [displayName_lower] => jody dunn [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 22885014 ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [displayName] => Jody dunn [pushnotification] => YES [readreceipt] => YES [username] => Jody.dunn@hotmail.com [firstLaunch] => Yes [usernameFix] => jodydunn [displayName_lower] => jody dunn [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 22885014 ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [displayName] => 1 [pushnotification] => 1 [readreceipt] => 1 [username] => 1 [firstLaunch] => 1 [usernameFix] => 1 [displayName_lower] => 1 [userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends] => 1 [qbUserID] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => oBBU5lwrAk [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-01-17 23:09:42.008000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-01-17 23:09:46.529000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 )
```

So I can get other fields, but there is not existing email.

How can I get emails. Please let me know.

Comment: Whats the output of `print_r($objArray);`?

Comment: dunno try `$one['email'] = $obj->get('email');`, source of madness https://hotexamples.com/examples/parse/ParseUser/query/php-parseuser-query-method-examples.html

Comment: thanks @Enstage I added print_r result on my post

Comment: thanks @Lawrence Cherone, and I have tried with get('email') and the result is same.

Comment: the users email is in username so  use `$one['email'] =  $obj->username;`

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone. I know username are almost same as email, But there is something different. So I can't use username. Please explain better method.

Comment: there is **no** email property in the object, so you cant access it.

Comment: thanks @Lawrence Cherone

Answer (score 0):

The **email** property you are looking for is an *optional* property on an instance of `ParseUser`. You should check for it's existence before assuming it's there.

If you took at when you signup the only required fields are **password** and **username**. If an email is not provided and set beforehand (such as via `$user->setEmail('...')`) there will be none to access afterwards.

With that being said the **username** property is your next best bet to having a valid email on a user, assuming they signed up with an email as a username that is. Other than that you can always require your users to submit an email as during signup, or require the username to be an email (which works pretty well!).

Comment: Thanks @montymxb, As you said, I have not done (such as $user->setEmail('...')) beforehand. But on Parse Dashboard User table, there is existing an 'email' field. So I think I can get that 'email' field value.

Comment: Yes you are correct, there is a registered **email** field for the `_User` class. However, if no email has been set the default value is `null`. You can always check if a `ParseObject` has data for a given field by calling `$obj->has('field-name');`.

Answer (score 0):

The email field does exist,you just need the masterKey to get it.
use `$query->find( true );` and provide the masterKey with `ParseClient::initialize` and you should get the email.